# How can i import two dimensional arrays from a csv file using python and the pandas library?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, csv

Im working on a project that requires i import data from a csv file
what ive tried looks like this:

code:

```
import Pandas as pd
a_xyz = []

df = pd.read_csv('parachute jump.csv', sep = ';', decimal = '.', comment = '#')

a_xyz_mg= df['a_values'].tolist()
```

the csv file looks like this:

```
[x1, y1, z1]  
[x2, y2, z2]  
[x3, y3, z3]
```

I want the output to be a two dimensional array that looks like this:

```
a_xyz = [[x1, y1 z1], [x2, y2, z2], [x3, y3, z3]]
```

and if i ask for x1 like this:

```
a_xyz[0][0]
```

i want the output to be x1
Currently the output is

```
print(a_xyz[0][0])
= x
```

meaning i get the first letter not the first element.
Also, the objects are put in '', making it hard to make them float

#Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Hello, what output are you getting currently? It would help to provide you the right steps to get to your desired output.

Comment: Hi, edited the post @KarthikNayak

Answer (score 0):

this can be done without pandas using list comprehension

```
data = open('parachute jump.csv', 'r').read().split('\n')
data = [[d for D.split(';')] for D in data]
```

if you want d to be an integer or a float then use int(d) or float(d)

Comment: There's a few errors here: `[d for D.split(';')]` is missing an `in`, the original data doesn't have semicolons, and I don't think this deals with the brackets in the original data.